# Issue with WFFM form being created in "en" language instead of specified language

Tags: wffm, multilingual, mvc-forms

I have the following scenario:

- I have installed Sitecore 8.2 update 7
- I have installed WFFM module

I am trying to add an `MVC Form` rendering into a layout details of a page that I have opened in another language `de-DE`. I want to create a new data source for my rendering.

When I choose `Create a blank form` option from the data source dialog, then the newly created form has the `en` language version. I was expecting this to be the same `de-DE` language as for my page.

[image: screen showing insert form dialog]

Is this expected behavior? Is there a configuration setting to allow me to fix this? Or is this an issue with Sitecore/WFFM module?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you try to set Default Content Language for that user to German? Would that help? https://community.sitecore.net/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/8/defaultlng.png

Comment: Unfortunately not really since user can edit multiple languages

Comment: I contacted Sitecore helpdesk and they provided a fix for it

Comment: Hi @Vic any chance you can share your solution or fix from Sitecore help desk here as well?